# Chrome - faster way to specify URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, search, url

I do a lot of my searches like this -

```
fb dominos // searches dominos on facebook's search
amz pasta // searches amazon for pasta
```

This works because I can tell Chrome to do facebook search when I enter fb in the address bar. Likewise, I have taught Chrome to do amazon search when I type amz in the address bar.

---

What I need, is a similar way to specify URLs using a shorthand, something I can type in the address bar so I don't have to open my bookmarks tab and point and click. Eg. Suppose there is a website called `www.foobar.com`, which has a menu, so the pages I visit look like -

```
www.foobarLongName.com/menu/macAndCheese
www.foobarLongName.com/menu/mashedPotato
www.foobarLongName.com/menu/sirloin
www.foobarLongName.com/menu/chicken
```

Like with search, is there a way to do the following from the address bar-

```
foobar chicken // Should open www.foobarLongName.com/menu/chicken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. This can be done through "Manage your search engines" also. Just like with search, use %s for input string. Eg.

```
www.foobarLongName.com/menu/%s          // your search path
foobar                                  // your annotation
```

Now, `foobar chicken` will take you to `www.foobarLongName.com/menu/chicken`

Comment: Consider this answer accepted. I am not going to bother accepting in 2 days.